# Backward lookup in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Following are my model classes.

```
class Categories(models.Model):
  name= models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Values(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
  language = models.CharField(max_length=7)
  category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Lets say I have already got list of Values. Now I want to get name of the Category to which this Value object is related to. How can I do that ?
Will appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming your classes to the singular versions: Category and Value. In any case if you already have the Values object, you can get the Categories.name, simply with `Values.category.name`

Comment: In what situation you need to get category name? To filter values queryset by category name or you need to get category name for each single value record?

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: @Charnel yes i wanted to display category name for each single value record

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch that with:

```
myValue.category.name # name of myValue
```

If you are fetching multiple `Value` objects, then you can use [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to boost retrieving the `Category` objects:

```
values = Value.objects.select_related('category')
for value in values:
    print(value.category.name)
```

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Value` instead of <s>`Values`</s>, and `Category` instead of <s>`Categories`</s>.

Comment: Thank you for your response. your answer really helped me.